# trying to read a text file in clojure and insert the data into a list or a vector

Tags: clojure

So basically my question is I was trying to read a data from a text file which is numbers like this: "1 5 3 8 9 3  23 67 90" and i wanted to read them number by number and put this in a list or a vector or array. However this is my first time coding with Clojure and that is why i am asking this question.

what i did so far is this which i am sure it is not correct.

```
(def nums11 (slurp "C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\100.txt"))
```

However this will only read the file as one string. so i decided to add this line

```
(clojure.string/split nums11 #" ")
```

is there any way to add them, after i split them, into a list or a vector or array.

or maybe there is an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You are in the right path already, so I'll try to explain what's next:

The function `clojure.string/split` returns a `vector` of Strings. The vector in Clojure is a *collection* that implements the Java interface `java.util.List` so you are done if all you needed was to turn the contents of the file into a collection of Strings representing the numbers (to turn these into actual numbers, read on).

Probably you want to manipulate the elements as *actual* numbers. In Clojure, you'll need to use some function to turn each String into a number (say `"34"` into the actual number 34). There are two simple ways: using Java interop and call `Integer.parseInt(...)` or use a function provided by Clojure that is able to read a String and return a whatever it represents (eg. `read-string`).

Since we need to call a function (`read-string`) to every element of the list of Strings representing numbers, we'll use `map`, a function that takes a function `f` and a collection `xs`, and calls a the function `f` on every element of `xs`, returning the result as another list.

If we glue it all together, it will be something like the following (I'll use `let` to give names to the intermediate results):

```
(let [file-contents   (slurp "C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\100.txt")                                                                                                                                 
      nums-as-strings (clojure.string/split file-contents #" ")                                                                                                             
      numbers         (map read-string nums-as-strings)]
```

... here the list of numbers will be on `numbers`; and now you can perform operations on them, such as summing all of them:

```
(reduce + numbers) ;; Compute the sum of all the numbers
```

There are a number of small details that I've glossed over, but this should put you in the right track.

Comment: Man, you have no idea how much these information are helpful for me. Thank you so much for your help. I tried to vote for your answer but it seems i cant because my account is new.

Comment: Be super careful around read-string - it can be very convenient, however it also has security implications. In general, I’d be specific about what I was parsing.

Comment: Ya, I'd just use `Long/parseLong` here.

Comment: it’s a shame there isn’t a clj/cljs neutral one - https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-2451 seems to fix this and more